# Lightning out App error in callback function, related list button display

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-out

I am trying to use a visualforce page a with lightning out component in order to transition off of a javascript button.  However, when testing the functionality I receive the following error message: Lightning out App error in callback function

Visualforce Page:

```
 <apex:includeLightning />

  <div id="lightning" />

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:PESRefreshStudentApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:PESRefreshStudentStatus",
   {
          "recordId" : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
       },
        "myDivId",
        function(component) {
            console.log('component created');
            console.log(component);
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Application:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
<aura:dependency resource="c:PESRefreshStudentStatus"/>
</aura:application>
```

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component controller= "ProgramRequirementsUtility" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="displayMessage" type="String" default="" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Refresh Student Status"  onclick="{!c.handleClick }" />
<p>{!v.displayMessage}</p>

</aura:component>
```

Lightning Controller:

```
({
 doInit : function(component) {
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log('inside component' + component.get("v.recordId"));
},


handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
console.log('inside onclick' + component.get("v.recordId")); 
    var oppId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log(oppId);
        var action = component.get("c.updateProgramEligibilityStatusWS");
        action.setParams({  "o" : oppId }); 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log('success');
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

            } else if (state == "ERROR" ) { 
                console.log('error');
                // Did not catch on the Server Side
                component.set("v.displayMessage", "An error has occurred. Changes to the record will not be saved.");

            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);


}
})
```

I've done a lot of searching but still don't see where I'm going sideways. Any suggestions?